# Responsive pre tag

Tags: html, css, iphone

I **simply** want to *show terminal output on a Webpage*. Atm I'm using a [pre tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-pre-element) to do that with `pre { white-space: pre-wrap; }` as you can see upon http://irc.dabase.com/.

My problem is that when I rotate my iPhone6 IOS device, it often doesn't reformat properly. **Why** is this? Can you offer some good CSS rules to make this use case of *showing terminal output on a Webpage* better?

[image: Unresponsive pre tag]

Comment: Does seem strange that the browser is not resizing the tag like it would on a desktop. Perhaps switch to another block-level tag and switch out the font to `monospace`?

Comment: I remember there was a rotion bug on ios around for some time... it may be that the effect you are talking about is related to this. Does the font gets zoomed? does it appear when you rotate from portrait to landscape, or the other way? or both?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Here are the rules you need explained step by step:

Select all `pre` elements (set this to `pre#yourID` or `pre.yourClass` to select a specific `pre`)

```
pre {
```

Allow pre to wrap at word breaks and line breaks. Unlike `pre-line`, `pre-wrap` will *not* modify your terminal output at *all*. `pre-line` will modify your terminal output by condensing whitespace into one whitespace which could make finding exact phrases difficult or mess with whitespace column formatting! See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

```
  white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Make sure that words that go past the end of the element break off instead of being hidden (like links for examples)

```
  word-wrap: break-word;
```

This part is *optional* Justify the text so that it fully fills the line. Spaces become wider but their number is *not* increased.

```
  text-align: justify;

}
```

Optionally, this rule can be fit into a [media-query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) so that it only applies in the mobile version. But I believe there is no harm in applying this rule to all screen sizes by simply omitting a media-query.

In the event that the wider version of your iphone makes your `pre` rule stop working, you should check to see if there isn't already a `media-query` in place that is applying a rule to the `pre` when the screen reaches a certain size.

You can also try intentionally creating a `media-query` for the wider version, which may re-initialize the styles if there is some kind of bug going on.

For example:

Include rule that applies to smallest possible version

Rule A:

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Then *in addition to rule A* include another rule to re-initialize styles at landscape orientation

Rule B:

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape)
    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align: justify;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't look good to me http://s.natalian.org/2016-10-14/34691470.mp4 :/

Comment: Try adding *both* rules. The one that applies to the smallest possible version *and* the media one so `pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: justify;
}` *and* `@media all and (orientation:landscape)
    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align: justify;
    }
}`

Comment: Basically troubleshooting is like this: step 1: use rule A > step 2: if rule A doesnt work use rule A *and* rule B

Answer (score 4):

You can try this to achieve -

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-line;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

You Can Try It Once

Answer (score 0):

This worked nicely for me when I had pre tag inside of a table and code below made pre tag stay responsive to the table column width. Credits to: https://techstacker.com/responsive-pre-tags-css/

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```